# Sqllite python select query

Tags: python, database, sqlite

If for example I had this database:

```
id  result
__________
1     55
2     67
```

And a function isPrime(number) which returns a boolean true or false if the number is prime,

Is there anyway for me to select numbers based on if isPrime = true;

something like this..

```
"SELECT * FROM DB WHERE result.isPrime()"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: if `isPrime()` is a Python function, then no, you cannot call that function inside your query because the query is executed inside the database, and there is not Python interpreter or python data types inside the database.

Comment: IIRC, the python sqlite bindings let you write user defined functions in Python that can be called from SQL statements.

Comment: @Shawn do you know where get documentation on this?

Comment: The python sqlite documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `conn` is a sqlite connection object, something like:

```
conn.create_function("isprime", 1, isPrime)
```

should let you call the function in SQL statements executed by that connection.

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM db WHERE isprime(result)")
```